# How to handle same node of firebase open in multiple tabs using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I have firebase nodes "formbuilder_1", "formbuilder_2", "formbuilder_3" etc.
If node "formbuilder_1" open in one tab and when user open same node in another then alert message show it is already open in tab. Same example as like online excel sheet.
How can we do it.

Here is my code:

```js
 $.urlParam = function (name) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
    .exec(window.location.href);
  if (results == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  return results[1] || 0;
}
let caseId = $.urlParam('case_id');
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set, onValue, child, update, get, query } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.2/firebase-database.js";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration 
 
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBQlm0cLrmY19nDXyRQRm_C_51gulT0mRY",
  authDomain: "devt-23a3b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "devt-23a3b",
  storageBucket: "devt-23a3b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "949860997571",
  appId: "1:949860997571:web:d398ef26b70791de75c576"
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

const formBuilderRef = ref(database, 'formbuilder');
const formSettingRef = child(formBuilderRef, 'form_setting');
const sectionsRef = child(formBuilderRef, 'sections');
const rowsRef = child(formBuilderRef, 'rows');
const formBuilderRefT = ref(database, 'formbuilder_' + caseId);
const formField = child(formBuilderRefT, 'fields');

// Create a new Broadcast Channel with a unique name
const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('firebase_channel');

$(document).ready(function () {
  // ...

  // form field setting for testing.....
  const fieldObject = { [`name`]: '' };
  checkNodeExists(formBuilderRefT, (node) => {
    console.log("_check node ", node)
    if (node) {
      onValue(formField, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log("Received data:", data);
        // Update the UI or perform other actions based on the received data
        
        // Broadcast the updated data to all open tabs
        broadcastChannel.postMessage(data);
      });
    } else {
      set(formField, fieldObject);
    }
  });

  // ...

  $("body").on('keyup', '.user_input', function () {
    let defaultValue = $(this).val();
    const updateObject = { [`name`]: defaultValue };
    checkNodeExists(formBuilderRefT, (node) => {
      console.log("_check node ", node)
      set(formField, updateObject);
    });
  });

  // Listen for messages from other tabs
  broadcastChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
    const data = event.data;
    console.log("Received broadcasted data:", data);
    // Update the UI or perform other actions based on the received data
  };
});

function checkNodeExists(formBuilderRefT, callback) {
  get(formBuilderRefT)
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        callback(true)
      } else {
        callback(false)
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      callback(false)
    });
}
```

This is js fiddle example.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/29era35f

[image]

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simpler than you think you don't need to use firebase at all to make it work, so you can simplify your use case into sending `caseId` variable to other tabs.

```js
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('firebase_channel');

const tabs = [];

let case_id = document.querySelector('#case-id');

run.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const new_case_id = case_id.value;
    if (tabs.includes(new_case_id)) {
        alert('Tab "${new_case_id}" taken');
    } else {
        channel.postMessage(new_case_id);
        alert(`Tab processing ${new_case_id}`);
    }
})

channel.onmessage = ({data}) => {
    tabs.push(data);
};
```

```html
<input id="case-id"/>
<button id="run">run</button>
```

It seems the snippet doesn't work on StackOverflow, probably because of Sandboxed environment. But you can try This CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/PoxGmjW

In case of your code you need to get case_id from URL.

Also note that to get a URL search param you can use this code instead of a regex:

```js
const case_id = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('case_id');
```

You don't need any library for this